# Sublime Text 3 Top Editor padding

Tags: text, editor, padding, sublimetext

I would like to increase the top padding between the window title bar and Sublime Text editor frame. The text should be like 5px under the title bar, instead of starting right away. Is that possible somehow, and if yes, how?

Can't add images yet so here's the URL https://i.stack.imgur.com/oucB5.png

Also, I've hidden the tabs and menu bar.

Answer (score -3):

I think that there is no configuration option to do this. But, try this one:

```
 {
    "line_padding_top": 20,
    "line_padding_bottom": -20
 }
```

It's a trick. Hope it's useful!

Comment: It moves the first line yeah, but screws everything else too. The line selection and caret are acting very weird :D

Comment: This is a bad hack yeah. It misaligns everything.